# How to get rid of the boxes around the piechart in jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I try to render simple [piechart](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) by jqplot js library. It works perfectly on most of browsers. But especially on MacOs I get pie inscribed polygon.

[image]

    How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: But *any* browser in MacOS?

Comment: definitely in chrome in MacOs